# Ionic : Image Cropping

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework and cordova. I have learnt to use the camera plugin.
Now after getting the image, I want to crop a part of it. The cropping aspect ratio must not be static, i.e, the cropping box should be scalable ( in up, down, right, left directions).

I went through [jeduan/cordova-plugin-crop](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-crop) but was not able to understand as it used Ionic v2, and I am working with ionic v1.

Please guide me to achieve this..
Is there any plugin to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `allowEdit: true` property for crop image get by camera:

```
var options = {
    maximumImagesCount: 1,
    quality: 75,
    targetWidth: 500,
    targetHeight: 500,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    correctOrientation: true,
    allowEdit: true
};

$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options)
    .then(function (imageData) {

    // here imageData have crop image

    // do anything with crop image 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> was not able to understand as it used Ionic v2

The main api for this plugin is provided for `javascript`. You are not have to manage it in angular way or a `ngCordova` module. Just use javascript syntax into your controller.

```
plugins.crop(function success () {

}, function fail () {

}, '/path/to/image', options)
```

Note that you are included `cordova.js` in your index.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using [jr-rop](https://github.com/JrSchild/jr-crop) library and it uses pure Angular approach.
You can use it as follows.

```
$jrCrop.crop({
    url: url,
    width: 200,
    height: 200
}).then(function(canvas) {
    // success!
    var image = canvas.toDataURL();
}, function() {
    // User canceled or couldn't load image.
});
```

After cropping it returns canvas object that you can manipulate further if needed.

Regards.